# Regular expression to match when a word doesn't exist

Tags: java, regex, apache-commons

I'm debugging some Java code that uses `RegexFileFilter` from Apache Commons IO with the following regex:

```
(?:custpartnum).*(?:8798518684708).*
```

This matches the following strings:

```
custpartnum-en-8798518684708.csv_20180612152233580
custpartnum-en-8798518684708.csv_filtered_20180612152300971
```

I'm trying to tell it to not match on the string containing `filtered`?

I tried this but it still matched both strings:

```
(?:custpartnum).*(?:8798518684708).*(?!filtered)
```

Comment: "Not Contain" is very tricky to achieve in Regular Expression. Consider matching for the filter and handling the negation in your java program code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Answer (score 0):

You can match files with only digits after the `.csv` :

```
custparnum[^.]*8798518684708.csv_\d*
```

I took the opportunity to remove your `(?:non-capturing groups)` that likely serve no purpose (they'd be useful if you had to modify them with a quantifier).

Answer (score 0):

You could move the negative lookahead to before the `.*` part and update it to match any character zero or more times followed by filtered.

This way you are first asserting using the negative lookahead that after you have matched `8798518684708` there should not be `filtered` on the right side.

[`(?:custpartnum).*(?:8798518684708)(?!.*filtered).*`](https://regex101.com/r/Vzh7qx/1)

You might use an updated version without the non capturing groups:

[`custpartnum.*8798518684708(?!.*filtered).*`](https://regex101.com/r/Vzh7qx/2)